# bluetooth problem mei_me 0000:00:16.0: Could not read IF version

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

I keep getting these messages on boot and have not been able to use my computer's built in bluetooth. I am extremely new to ubuntu, but can enter any terminal commands necessary.

The messages I am getting are:
mei_me 0000:00:16.0: Could not read IF version
Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout

Comment: What is the message you keep getting - bluetooth problem mei_me 0000:00:16:0?

Comment: I get 
mei_me 0000:00:16.0: Could not read IF version
and
Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout